# "truffle migrate --network ropsten" stuck after compiling

Tags: truffle, ropsten, truffle-migration

I am trying to redeploy a contract on Ropsten Testnet using the command:

```
truffle migrate --reset -f 1567182283 --network ropsten
```

Here, "1567182283" is the prefix of my migration file. Upon executing, it gets stuck after compiling the contract:

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.
```

I even left it overnight but there was no message or anything, it just gets stuck like this for more than 6-7 hours. Below is my truffle-config.js:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const fs = require('fs');
const mnemonic = fs.readFileSync(".secret").toString().trim();
module.exports = {
  // rpc: {
  //   host: "localhost",
  //   port: 8545
  // },
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 9545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
      websockets: true
    },
    ropsten: {
      provider: new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/KEY"),
      network_id: 3,       // Ropsten's id
      gas: 550000000,        // Ropsten has a lower block limit than mainnet
      networkCheckTimeout: 1000000000,
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
      skipDryRun: true,
    },
    rinkeby: {
      provider: function() {
        return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/KEY");
      },
      network_id: 4,
      networkCheckTimeout: 1000000000,
      timeoutBlocks: 200
    }
  }
}
```

Any way to solve this problem? 
I have tried running the command without --reset and -f as well but still the same.

Comment: Delete your `build` folder and try again.

Comment: I have tried that as well. Does not work

Answer (score 0):

Your network timeout is very long.  delete that line.  It will then give you an error telling you what to do next.  Probably to do with lack of reply to your infura ping.